# Authorization: Bearer {token} in the header of REST API

Tags: php, rest, api

I am having troubles sending header in an API that handles authentication using "`Authorization: Bearer {token}`" in the header.

I am trying to send the header as

```
'Authorization' => $token
```

The `$token` variable will have the authorization token as needed.

But I get result as follow

```
HTTP_Request2_Response {#319 ▼
  #version: "1.1"
  #code: 401
  #reasonPhrase: "Unauthorized"
```

I am wondering if I am sending the Authorization header correctly.

Comment: Can we see the curl code that you used? Be sure to scrub/truncate any secret info

Comment: @Cowgirl are you able the endpoint by using POSTMAN ? because you can specify the Authorisation Bearer in the postman and hit the endpoint which you are trying to hit.

Comment: @zenwraight I cannot send it through POSTMAN because the token is unique for every request, and I cannot retrieve it through postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by passing it like this

`Authentication: Bearer : $token`

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass token as part of header with key `x-access-token`